# SQlite-Foreign key

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, sqliteopenhelper, android-database

hello i'm a beginner in sqlite in android i made a 2 tables database and i'm trying to make a foreing key in the second table which is the id of the first table here is the code and i would appreciate if you tell me if there is other errors in the code espiciallly in the queries thank you in advance

```
package com.example.hp.memorybackup;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Created by hp on 13/04/2015.
 */
public class SanaHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "memorydatabase";
        private static final String TABLE_NOTE_NAME = "NOTETABLE";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String UID_NOTE = "_idnote";
    private static final String TITRE = "Titre";
    private static final String OBJET = "Objet";
    private static final String PRAM_N = "Prametres_note";
    private static final String CREATE_NOTE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NOTE_NAME + "(" + UID_NOTE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + TITRE + " VARCHAR (255)" + OBJET + "VARCHAR (255)" + PRAM_N + "VARCHAR (255) ;";
        private static final String TABLE_USER_NAME = "USERTABLE";
    private static final String UID_USER = "_iduser";
    private static final String NOM = "Nom";
    private static final String PRENOM = "Prenom";
    private static final String DATE_NAISS="Date_Naiss";
    private static final String E_MAIL = "E-mail";
    private static final String LOGIN = "Login";
    private static final String MOT_PASSE = "Mot-passe";
    private static final String CREATE_USER = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_USER_NAME + "(" +  UID_USER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + NOM + " VARCHAR (255)" + PRENOM + "VARCHAR (255)" + DATE_NAISS + "DATE "
            + LOGIN + " VARCHAR (255) "+MOT_PASSE+" VARCHAR (255);";





    private Context context;

    public SanaHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "DATABASE_NAME", null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_USER);
        } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error? Please post your log cat trace.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some spaces and some commas here:

```
private static final String CREATE_NOTE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NOTE_NAME + "(" + UID_NOTE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + TITRE + " VARCHAR (255)" + OBJET + "VARCHAR (255)" + PRAM_N + "VARCHAR (255) ;";
```

Which has to be

```
private static final String CREATE_NOTE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTE_NAME + "(" + UID_NOTE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TITRE + " VARCHAR (255), " + OBJET + " VARCHAR (255), " + PRAM_N + " VARCHAR (255)";
```

And here:

```
private static final String CREATE_USER = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_USER_NAME + "(" +  UID_USER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + NOM + " VARCHAR (255)" + PRENOM + "VARCHAR (255)" + DATE_NAISS + "DATE, "
        + LOGIN + " VARCHAR (255), " + MOT_PASSE+" VARCHAR (255);";
```

Which has to be

```
private static final String CREATE_USER = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER_NAME + "(" +  UID_USER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NOM + " VARCHAR (255), " + PRENOM + " VARCHAR (255), " + DATE_NAISS + " DATE, "
        + LOGIN + " VARCHAR (255), " + MOT_PASSE + " VARCHAR (255)";
```

I'd also avoid the **hyphen character** (**-**) and use the underscore (**_**), instead.

I.e.: `E-mail` => `E_Mail` or `eMail`